# JFrame doesn't appear unless method invoked in main

Tags: java, swing, class, user-interface, jframe

I have a class which create a JFrame with an image but everytime I create the class and run the method to instantiate it, it doesn't appear. However, I have noticed that if I was to create the exact same class and run the same method in the main then the frame appears.

This is most of the code from the class with the JFrame that I am trying to create:

```
    JFrame myFrame= new JFrame();
    public void CreateFrame()
    {       
        JLabel background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("image.jpg"));

        myFrame.add(background);

        background.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
        myFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        myFrame.setSize(360,250);
        myFrame.setUndecorated(true);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        myFrame.setLocation((dim.width/2-170), dim.height/2-125);
        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

If I run the code

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.CreateFrame();
```

in a method in another class it doesn't come up. However, if I run the exact same code in a main method, it works.

For example, this doesn't work:

## Example 1

```
public class otherClass extends JFrame
{
    public void MethodA()
    {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        mc.CreateFrame();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        otherClass oc = new otherClass();
        oc.MethodA();
    }
}
```

but this does work

## Example 2

```
public class otherClass extends JFrame
{
    public void MethodA()
    {
        //CODE
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        otherClass oc = new otherClass();
        oc.MethodA();
        
        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        mc.CreateFrame();
    }
}
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Sorry if a stupid mistake, I'm still getting to grips with Java.
Thanks

## EDIT

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyClass
 {
    JFrame homeFrame = new JFrame();
    public void createFrame()
    {       

    JLabel background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images.jpg"));

    myFrame.add(background);

    background.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    
    myFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    myFrame.setSize(360,250);
    myFrame.setUndecorated(true);
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    myFrame.setLocation((dim.width/2-170), dim.height/2-125);
    myFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    myFrame.pack();
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
    durationOfTime();
}

public void durationOfTime()
{
    MainProgram mp = new MainProgram();
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = 0L;
    int count =0;
    while (elapsedTime < 2*1000) 
    {
        if(count==0)
        {
            mp.launchInitiation();
        }
        count+=1;
        
        elapsedTime = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;
    }
    myFrame.setVisible(false);
    mp.homeFrame.setVisible(true);
}

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    mc.createFrame();
  }
}
```

Full code from class with JFrame trying to make. I am trying to use this JFrame as a splash screen but whatever class I call

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.createFrame();
```

from, it just doesn't appear. Two seconds do pass by before my main GUI appears up but this method is supposed to be called in a login type frame. However, I have tested it with a blank JFrame / GUI to appear upon button click also and it still doesn't appear.

## EDIT2

I also previously tried this SplashScreen example by @ http://examples.oreilly.com/jswing2/code/ch08/SplashScreen.java  but I couldn't get it to work (same problem, appears when called from main but not when called from action listener)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SplashScreen extends JWindow {
  private int duration;
  public SplashScreen(int d) {
    duration = d;
  }

  // A simple little method to show a title screen in the center
  // of the screen for the amount of time given in the constructor
  public void showSplash() {
    JPanel content = (JPanel)getContentPane();
    content.setBackground(Color.white);

    // Set the window's bounds, centering the window
    int width = 450;
    int height =115;
    Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (screen.width-width)/2;
    int y = (screen.height-height)/2;
    setBounds(x,y,width,height);

    // Build the splash screen
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("oreilly.gif"));
    JLabel copyrt = new JLabel
      ("Copyright 2002, O'Reilly & Associates", JLabel.CENTER);
    copyrt.setFont(new Font("Sans-Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
    content.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    content.add(copyrt, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    Color oraRed = new Color(156, 20, 20,  255);
    content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(oraRed, 10));

    // Display it
    setVisible(true);

    // Wait a little while, maybe while loading resources
    ClassToLoad ctl = new ClassToLoad();
    try {
    Thread.sleep(duration); 
    ctl.initiate();
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    setVisible(false);
  }

  public void showSplashAndExit() {
    showSplash();
    System.exit(0);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Throw a nice little title page up on the screen first
    SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen(10000);
    // Normally, we'd call splash.showSplash() and get on with the program.
    // But, since this is only a test...
    splash.showSplashAndExit();
  }
}
```

I added the code in the lines with ClassToLoad and this SplashScreen is called on an action listener, what happens is the program waits the 2 seconds that I tell it to, no frame appears, and then the main class that I wanted to load while the splash screen is visible loads. I tried this method first but this didn't work which lead to me using the code listed above this edit

## EDIT 3

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
    JPanel thePanel = new JPanel(null); //layout
    JButton button = new JButton();

 public void startGUI()
 {
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    

    CREATEMYPANEL();
    this.add(thePanel);

    this.setTitle("NO_TITLE_SET");
    this.setSize(400,400);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(true);
 }

 public void CREATEMYPANEL()
 {
    button.setLocation(242,151);
    button.setSize(100,50);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    button.setText("button");
    thePanel.add(button);

 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {
    if(e.getSource()==button)
    {
         System.out.println("button has been pressed ");
         SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen(1000);
         splash.showSplash();
    }
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args )

 {
    TestFrame tf = new TestFrame();
    tf.startGUI();
 }
}
```

An example of where I call splash screen from. Still doesn't work. Also, just a note that the image I am loading is a local image

Apologies for bad question formatting

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @khelwood I have other classes where I can create other classes / frames from within methods in the way I have described; why any different in this example.

Comment: I just ran this code, both examples work. Whatever problem you have is not expressed in the code you've shown.

Comment: Why does `otherClass` extends `JFrame` and you're never using it? Also please follow the [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and use them consistently: `firstWordLowerCaseMember`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `FirstWordUpperCaseClass` and `ALL_UPPER_CASE_WORDS_CONSTANTS` so it's easier for you and us to read your code

Comment: I know that the image you're trying to load is stored locally but haven't you tried loading it from the URL? That would tell us if it's your image not being loaded and thus your frame has a size of 0, 0

Comment: I just tried it with your URL, still  no image

Comment: It's almost a mcve, where are you calling that code? In the Splashscreen code? It doesn't compile `thePanel();` is not a method, also you should't be using `null` layout...

Comment: @Frakcool yeah that was a mistake was supposed to say CREATEMYPANEL(); , doesn't work even if I change null layout. Which code are you referring to when you ask where I'm calling the code? If you look at edit 2 and edit 3 it would show you a full example of my code that doesn't work

Comment: Edit 2 is a copy of the `SplashScreen` class... Is `ClassToLoad` your `TestFrame`?

Comment: @Frakcool ClassToLoad is the main class of my program but my point is even if I omit the lines with ClassToLoad the image doesn't display

Comment: Because the image is not being loaded! Post how you tried with an URL it works fine for me...

Comment: @Frakcool exactly the same but with try{
     label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL("http://www.cqsisu.com/data/wallpapers/5/718448.gif")));
 }
 catch(Exception ex){}

Comment: Try the code in the edit of my answer below

Comment: @Frakcool even this label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL("http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/6/6b/175Togepi.png/250px-175Togepi.png")));
        }  doesn't work

Comment: @Frakcool copied and pasted exactly the same! no image frame loads

Comment: Then it's out of my hands, that code works fine for me... Probably your PC is too slow to show it in the beggining or I don't know. It takes like half second to show the splashscreen on my computer and after 10s it shows your `TestFrame`

Comment: @Frakcool that's fine no problem. thanks for all your help. your first recommended code works so i might just try that out

Comment: If you don't understand something in it as you stated then just comment what part don't you understand...

Answer (score 3):

Your code works for me except for some details I noticed:

1. You're calling [`setSize(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setSize(java.awt.Dimension)) and then calling [`pack()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack()). Probably your image isn't being loaded and thus your `JFrame` has a size of 0, 0. (And thus it looks like it never appears). `.pack()` and `.setSize(...)` are mutually exclusive.
2. You're setting the `JLabel`'s layout manager to `FlowLayout` but never adding anything to it. (You can safely remove it)
3. I see you're importing [`java.util.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) if you want to dispose the `JFrame` after 2 seconds, then you should be using a [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead. Otherwise you could get problems related to threading.
4. Also don't forget to place your program on the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) as Swing is not thread safe

Following above recommendations you can have this code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SplashscreenSample {
    private JFrame myFrame;
    private JLabel background;
    private Timer timer;

    public void createFrame() {

        timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                myFrame.dispose();
                @SuppressWarnings("serial")
                JFrame frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName()) {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(200, 200);
                    }
                };
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                timer.stop();
            }
        });

        myFrame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
        try {
            background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL("http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/6/6b/175Togepi.png/250px-175Togepi.png")));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myFrame.add(background);

        timer.setInitialDelay(2000);
        timer.start();

        myFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        myFrame.setUndecorated(true);
        myFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        myFrame.pack();
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        myFrame.setLocation((dim.width/2-170), dim.height/2-125);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new SplashscreenSample().createFrame()); 
    }
}
```

---

Or you can use the [Splashscreen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) class...

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JWindow;

public class SplashScreen extends JWindow {
    private int duration;

    public SplashScreen(int d) {
        duration = d;
    }

    // A simple little method to show a title screen in the center
    // of the screen for the amount of time given in the constructor
    public void showSplash() {
        ImageIcon icon = null;
        try {
            icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://www.cqsisu.com/data/wallpapers/5/718448.gif"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        JPanel content = (JPanel) getContentPane();
        content.setBackground(Color.white);

        // Set the window's bounds, centering the window
        int width = icon.getIconWidth();
        int height = icon.getIconHeight();
        Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = (screen.width - width) / 2;
        int y = (screen.height - height) / 2;

        setBounds(x, y, width, height);

        // Build the splash screen
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
        JLabel copyrt = new JLabel("Copyright 2002, O'Reilly & Associates", JLabel.CENTER);
        copyrt.setFont(new Font("Sans-Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
        content.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        content.add(copyrt, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        Color oraRed = new Color(156, 20, 20, 255);
        content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(oraRed, 10));

        // Display it
        setVisible(true);

        // Wait a little while, maybe while loading resources
        loadResources();

        setVisible(false);
    }

    public void loadResources() {
        TestFrame tf = new TestFrame();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(duration);
            tf.startGUI();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen(10000);
        splash.showSplash();
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually tried an implementation of the SplashScreen class first but I was having similar problems. Everytime I called the method, the frame wouldn't appear. So I gave up and tried a new way. Thanks for your answer. Much appreciated

Comment: @15150776 Whenever you try something add that to your question explaining why it didn't work for you (recommended including the [mcve] of that intent), so people don't have to guess what you've tried and what you don't. Did my code help you? Or it didn't? If not, please explain why.

Comment: also  I didn't directly use all your code but rather tried the modifications from the errors you suggested, still couldn't get it to work. I'm still a beginner in Java and don't really want to use your code when I don't really understand it

Comment: @15150776 what don't you understand? If I run the code (just changing the "oreily.gif" because I don't own that gif) for this line: `new URL("http://www.cqsisu.com/data/wallpapers/5/718448.gif")` it works. I can see the gif playing

Comment: Yeah it works but whenever I call it from another class it doesn't work. Also, your code is just a little advanced for me. Not that I don't totally understand it

Comment: @15150776 "your code is just a little advanced for me"* What part? Again, for better help sooner post a valid [mcve] how are you calling it from another class?

Comment: @15150776 BTW did you read the comments on the SplashScreen code? It's calling `showSplashAndExit()` method, which forces the program closing with `System.exit(0);` change in the main the call of `showSplashAndExit()` to `showSplash()` and that's it.

Comment: Yeah so in my other class I was calling      SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen(1000);      splash.showSplash(); but what happened was the actual frame wouldn't appear, but the class i wanted to load up after it would load after the time

Comment: @15150776 then you needed to call `splash.showSplash()` Still unsure what your problem is, you don't post the main class with the action listener that produces the problem. Load the images with the URL as shown above that would help

Comment: I'll edit question to show you an example. Wherever I am calling the method from image won't show. I created a blank test frame and still didn't work

Comment: @15150776 That's what I've been asking since yesterday!

Comment: @Frakcool: you appear to understand the original poster's problem fine. He's using `Thread.sleep` on the Swing event thread and instead should be using a Swing Timer as you've recommended and have demonstrated.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @HovercraftFullOfEels :) I appretiate your time to look into it

Comment: One more issue is the ClassToLoad code, code which is **not** shown. If this code takes a long time to load, and does not involve GUI code directly, then it will need to be called from a background thread, such as  within a SwingWorker's doInBackground method, and then the main gui or splash screen will need to be notified when its running is complete, such as by adding a PropertyChangeListener to the SwingWorker and listening for `SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE.

Comment: Agree with you Hovercraft, I forgot to mention that, I hope that @15150776 takes that into consideration too

Answer (score 0):

Try creating and setting the frame visible in a constructor of the class.
Could it be that while your program is counting

```
 while (elapsedTime < 2*1000) 
    {
        if(count==0)
        {
            mp.launchInitiation();
        }
        count+=1;

        elapsedTime = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;
    }
```

it is blocking for said 2 seconds and waiting for this method to finish, return back to the create method and then just finish that one?

it seems this could be a better comment, but i need 50 rep for some reason to comment.

Comment: Hm, thanks. It's actually loading up now but still getting errors. The frame loads in the top left, not where the center and I get an IllegalStateComponentException saying the Frame is displayable, and so the rest of my code doesn't execute. Any idea what to do? Also, if I remove the line causing the error ( myFrame.setUndecorated(true)), the image just doesn't load in the frame. By the way, I have only set the frame as visible in the constructor

Comment: centering the frame: `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`

Comment: you could also `setLocationRelativeTo(GUIELEMENT X);`

Comment: i think it's `frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);`

Comment: the setUndecorated used to work before when the frame used to show when called from the main. I think it might have to do with the fact that the JFrame is visible and then setUndecorated is being called. My bigger problems however are that the image won't actually load properly. Either i get a black screen in the JFrame or the JFrame just doesn' appear

Comment: ah ok: one thing i learned the hard way: ALWAYS setVisible() LAST after every decoration has been made to the frame. otherwise you would have to call `frame.repaint();`....and for your image problem: I don't think I have the time to look completely into it today since it is in the middle of the night here, but if you coult not solve it by tomorrow i could try again. good luck solving the problem

Comment: no worries, thanks anyway. More help than anyone else that commented lol